# Difference between ем и ест

Tags: выбор-слова

What is the difference between ем и ест? As far as I know ем means to 'eat' and ест means 'eats or eating' but that is not how it is on various sites I have seen. How are they used?

Comment: Voting down because absolutely no self research! The difference is given in every basic grammar book or dictionary.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: This is conjugation я ем (I eat), ты ешь( you eat), он, она, оно ест (he,she, it eats), мы едим(we eat), вы едите(you eat plural), они едят (they eat).

Comment: Try to explain what's confusing.

Comment: basically, my question is whether ест and ем are the same? Because sometimes the literal meaning of ест is used for ем and vice versa. But if you check up the meaning of the words in a dictionary their meaning aren't the same?

Comment: @Chris, really, verb conjugation is a very basic feature of Russian. You should read about it. *Ем* and *ест* are two forms of the same verb. http://masterrussian.com/verbs/est_sest.htm

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't understand that because I'm new to Russian and I'm learning Russian from Duolingo and things like those are not clear over there.

Comment: Duolingo is not intended to teach you a language (although they claim this). It's just not designed for that. Get you a grammar book.

Answer (score 1):

1. Я **ем** яблоко. (I am eating an apple.)
2. Он **ест** яблоко. (He eats an apple.)
3. Я хочу **есть**. (I want to eat.)
4. Он хочет **есть**. (He wants to eat.)